# Why does the range of this definite integral change?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

On a practice quiz for a  calculus one course I am taking there is a problem that asks to find the definite integral using substitution. Why does the range change from u=-1 to u=-2 where I drew the arrow?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: That appears to be a typo. You can see in the right hand side of that same line that they actually plug in -1 for the limit.

Comment: It's a typo most likely

Comment: Great thanks for clearing that up @bames

Comment: bames did a better job